# How to do a replacement field in R?

Tags: r

I am wondering how to do a replacement field for a set of named data in R. This is how I would do it in Python.

```
teams = ["Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Cardiff", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Fulham",
         "Huddersfield", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Tottenham", "Watford", "West Ham", "Wolves"]

for team in teams:
    print("{}_permutation = ".format(team), end="")

Arsenal_fixtures <- read.csv("Arsenal_fixtures.csv")
Bournemouth_fixtures <- read.csv("Bournmouth_fixtures.csv")
Brighton_fixtures <- read.csv("Brighton_fixtures.csv")
Burnley_fixtures <- read.csv("Burnley_fixtures.csv")
Cardiff_fixtures <- read.csv("Cardiff_fixtures.csv")
Chelsea_fixtures <- read.csv("Chelsea_fixtures.csv")
CrystalPalace_fixtures <- read.csv("CrystalPalace_fixtures.csv")
```

Comment: Could you share the desired output?

Comment: I want to make 20 40*40 matrices for each team in the league. I want each matrix to be called arsenal_permutation, bournmouth_permutation, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to use a loop to achieve the second part?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
teams = c("Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Cardiff", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Fulham",
         "Huddersfield", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Tottenham", "Watford", "West Ham", "Wolves")
paste0(teams,"_permutation = ")

 [1] "Arsenal_permutation = "        "Bournemouth_permutation = "   
 [3] "Brighton_permutation = "       "Burnley_permutation = "       
 [5] "Cardiff_permutation = "        "Chelsea_permutation = "       
 [7] "Crystal Palace_permutation = " "Everton_permutation = "       
 [9] "Fulham_permutation = "         "Huddersfield_permutation = "  
[11] "Leicester_permutation = "      "Liverpool_permutation = "     
[13] "Man City_permutation = "       "Man United_permutation = "    
[15] "Newcastle_permutation = "      "Southampton_permutation = "   
[17] "Tottenham_permutation = "      "Watford_permutation = "       
[19] "West Ham_permutation = "       "Wolves_permutation = "
```